# Return exact solution in one variable from Series as an option

Tags: series-expansion, scoping

I have a module which expands many functions, depending on expansion order input parameters.  Here's an MRE:

```
ExpandFuncs[xorder_, yorder_] :=
 Block[{func1, func2, exp1, exp2},
  func1 = 1/Sin[x+y];
  func2 = 1/Cos[x+y];
  exp1 = Normal[Series[func1,{x, 0, xorder}, {y, 0, yorder}]];
  exp2 = Normal[Series[func2,{x, 0, xorder}, {y, 0, yorder}]];
  Return[{exp1, exp2}];  
 ]
```

Sometimes, however, I'd like to get the functions to only expand in `y` and return the exact solution in `x`.  Is there a straightforward way to do this without introducing a bunch of `If` statements?  In practice, my module is working with many functions, so introducing exceptions would be a hassle. Is there some way to give `Series` an argument like `Infinity` for the expansion order? (I've looked but not found anything like that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the following function `expandFunc` which takes two arguments, the first is a list of variables, the second is a list of orders to expand in (with `Infinity` corresponding to "no expansion"):

```
expandFunc[vars_, orders_] := Function[{f},
  Series[f, 
   Sequence @@ If[#2 == \[Infinity], Nothing, {#1, 0, #2}] & @@@ 
    Transpose[{vars, orders}]
   ]
  ]
```

Simple usage example (note that I do not define it with `Normal`)

```
expandFunc[{x, y}, {1, \[Infinity]}][1/Sin[x + y]]
(* SeriesData[x, 0, {
Csc[y], -Cot[y] Csc[y]}, 0, 2, 1] *)
```

Your code can be rewritten with `expandFunc` as

```
ExpandFuncs[xorder_, yorder_] := 
 Block[{func1, func2, exp1, exp2},
  func1 = 1/Sin[x + y];
  func2 = 1/Cos[x + y];
  exp1 = Normal@expandFunc[{x, y}, {xorder, yorder}][func1];
  exp2 = Normal@expandFunc[{x, y}, {xorder, yorder}][func2];
  Return[{exp1, exp2}];]
```

### Update

I just thought of the solution of filtering any argument with `Infinity` as an order specification out of a call to a function `mySeries` which then just calls `Series` with the "valid" arguments. This also allows options to be passed.

```
Options[mySeries] = Options[Series];
mySeries[expr_, limits__, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {finiteLimits = {limits} /. {_, _, \[Infinity]} :> Nothing},
  Series[expr, Sequence @@ finiteLimits, 
   Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Series]]]
  ]
```

Taking the example for `Assumptions` from the documentation of `Series`:

```
mySeries[ArcCos[x], {x, 1, 1}, Assumptions -> (x > 1)]
(* SeriesData[x, 1, {Complex[0, 1] 2^Rational[1, 2]}, 1, 3, 2] *)
```

Comment: This is perfect! thank you!